# User-Assigned-Managed-Identity (UAMI) use with multiple ADF implementations across subscriptions and ARM template parameterization

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-managed-identity

I wonder if anyone has any experience on how to handle the User-Assigned-Managed-Identity (UAMI) use with the CICD pipelines in Azure DevOps when the UAMI are not the same across environments?

Consider this, if one  has Dev, Test and Prod subscriptions then each ADF implementation can have its own Azure subscription and possibly different UAMI configured.

The ARM template generation/publication from the Dev ADF will generate/publish the ARM template but it will not parameterized the “credentials” part where UAMI are defined as far as I can tell in my environment since it appears to do only for the ‘linked services’.

So how do we build the CICD pipeline for ADF if using ADF published ARM templates from dev ADF as artifacts?

This is the snippet of the ARM template published by ADF;

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/cred_uami')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "properties": {
            "type": "ManagedIdentity",
            "typeProperties": {
                "resourceId": "/subscriptions/<XXXXX-SUBID-XXXXX>/resourceGroups/<XXXX-RG-XXXX/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/XXXX-uami"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
]
```

}

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else need this in future, the solution for me is to over write the default parameter file, the details for this are available at;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters

I used the ADF default parameter file and added the following code to it and then provdied the value as part of the CICD pipeline for each environment.

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/credentials" : {
    "properties": {
        "typeProperties": {
            "resourceId": "="
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not working for me. The param isn't coming up in the published params json.